# How to allow access to base route without authentication in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I allow access to the base route while I have my Default permission classes set to IsAuthenticated in the global settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ],
}
```

I know you can just set permission_classes = [AllowAny] in the individual views.
But I want my base route to have the same i.e no permissions. Here is how i have the routes set in urls.py

```
router_public = DefaultRouter()
'''
PUBLIC ROUTES HERE
'''
router_public.register(
    r'cars', car_viewset.Car_Public_Viewset, base_name='Cars')
router_public.register(
    r'planes', plane_views.Plane_Public_ViewSet, base_name='Planes')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/admin/', include(router_admin.urls)),
    path('api/public/', include(router_public.urls)),
]
```

Since I have set permission_classes for cars and planes to AllowAny in the vews, I can access them without Authentication.

How can I do the same for the base route http://localhost:8000/api/public/ since there's no view associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide different permissions to different view class using **authenticated_class**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class ExampleClass(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
     permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
     [...]
```

use permission_classes in the view which you want to access through api/public/

Comment: Please review the question. I said I know how to allowany on individual views and I said api/public belongs to no view.

Comment: api/public will gonna  access  plane_views.Plane_Public_ViewSet and car_viewset.Car_Public_Viewset and this are two views,right?